# How can I correct this list mapping function?

Tags: python, excel, function, nested-lists

I'm attempting to make a python function which takes in a string of an excel formula and changes it to pseudo readable text, and vice versa according to this mapping.

```
mapping = {"'2020 Projects'!$I3" : "end_date",
"'2020 Projects'!$H3" : "start_date",
"'2020 Projects'!$L3" : "perc_baa",
"'2020 Projects'!$G3" : "prob",
"'2020 Projects'!$J3" : "monthly_rev",
"43951": "april_30_number",
"43922": "april_1_number",
"43952": "may_1_number",}
```

Right now I have this and getting incorrect results.

```
def code_to_ex(s):
    excel = s
    for word, code in mapping.items():
        excel = s.replace(code, word)
        print(excel)

def ex_to_code(s):
    code = s
    for word, code in mapping.items():
        code = s.replace(code, word)
        print(code)
```

Here's a sample input and output:

```
String ="IF('2020 Projects'!$H3>43922,yes,no)"

ex_to_code(String)
answer -> IF(start_date>apr1, yes no)

String2 = 'IF(start_date>apr30, no, yes)'
code_to_ex(String2)
answer -> 'IF(2020 Projects'!$H3>43951,no,yes)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variable excel is updated at every time.

So, you should change your function as follows.

```
def code_to_ex(s):
    for word, code in mapping.items():
        s = s.replace(code, word)
    print(s)

def ex_to_code(s):
    for word, code in mapping.items():
        s = s.replace(code, word)
    print(s)
```

Comment: Thanks this should work! however, wiill this change the original string? if yes, can I avoid that in any way?

Comment: Nope. It does not affect the original value. Please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your code. I hope I don't miss any, but let me know if anything is unclear:

```
mapping = {"'2020 Projects'!$I3" : "end_date",
"'2020 Projects'!$H3" : "start_date",
"'2020 Projects'!$L3" : "perc_baa",
"'2020 Projects'!$G3" : "prob",
"'2020 Projects'!$J3" : "monthly_rev",
"43951": "april_30_number",
"43922": "april_1_number",
"43952": "may_1_number",}

def code_to_ex(s):
    excel = s
    for word, code in mapping.items():
        # not excel = s.replace, since you want to continuously update excel
        excel = excel.replace(code, word)
    print(excel)

def ex_to_code(s):
    # renamed code to all_code, since you are iterating over mapping.items() with code
    all_code = s
    for word, code in mapping.items():
        # same issue as above
        all_code = all_code.replace(word, code)
    print(all_code)

String1 = "IF('2020 Projects'!$H3>43922,yes,no)"
String2 = 'IF(start_date>april_30_number, no, yes)'

ex_to_code(String1)
code_to_ex(String2)
```

Output:

```
IF(start_date>april_1_number,yes,no)
IF('2020 Projects'!$H3>43951, no, yes)
```

A word of warning, since this method is a little naive: you could get tripped up if a `code` is a substring of a `word` or vice-versa, since the mapping might be performed twice: e.g. for rules `{'AB': 'C', 'C': 'D'}`, the string `AB` might be mapped to `D`.